# Pipe never gets executed when server response with new data

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I created a subscription in my template to watch for changes to an object. The initial loading of the object displays the correct data for the property `tags`, when I add an item to the data it goes to a web server and returns a list of all the `tags` that are attached to the item (to keep the item in sync with the server). However, the newly added item isn't reflected on the page. I am not 100% sure why. I think it is because my `of()` statement but I am not sure. What I am seeing is that `zip().pipe()` never gets executed.

Do I need to use something other than `of`?

**Note:** I am trying to follow the declarative pattern to eliminate the usage of `.subscribe()`

**Sub-Note:** Once I get it working I plan on trying to remove the `subscribe` on this line `this.server.file().subscribe`

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-a9ljj8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

```js
export interface FileInfo {
  tags: string[];
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <input #tag /><button (click)="addTag(tag.value)">Add Tag</button>

  <div *ngIf="data$ | async as data">
    <div *ngFor="let tag of data.tags">{{ tag }}</div>
  </div>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  data$ = new Observable<FileInfo>();

  constructor(
    // Used to mimic server responses
    private readonly server: WebServer
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    // I plan on removing this subscribe once I get a grasp on this
    this.server.file().subscribe((img) => {
      this.data$ = of(img);
    });
  }

  addTag(newTag: string) {
    const data$ = this.server.save(newTag);
    this.data$.pipe(concatMap((i) => this.zip(data$)));
  }

  private zip(tags$: Observable<string[]>) {
    return zip(this.data$, tags$).pipe(
      tap((i) => console.log('zipping', i)),
      map(([img, tags]) => ({ ...img, tags } as FileInfo))
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you aren't subscribing to your observable in `addTag()`.

Comment: @BizzyBob I am trying to get my code to use the declarative pattern which doesn't use subscribe except for the `async` pipe found in the template as I have been having a hell of a time trying to use that pattern with this kind of setup where the data changes at a later date from a network call.

Comment: I was just pointing out the reason your logic wasn’t executing. If you don’t subscribe (whether via async pipe or otherwise) data won’t flow! You are defining a `data$` observable, but it is t being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you want to do is have a single observable source that emits the latest state of your object as new tags are added.  Then you can simply subscribe to this single observable in the template using the async pipe.

In order to accomplish this, you can create a dedicated stream that represents the updated state of your file's tags.

Here's an example:

```js
  private initialFileState$ = this.service.getFile();
  private addTag$ = new Subject<string>();
  private updatedfileTags$ = this.addTag$.pipe(
    concatMap(itemName => this.service.addTag(itemName))
  );

  public file$ = this.initialFileState$.pipe(
    switchMap(file => this.updatedfileTags$.pipe(
      startWith(file.tags),
      map(tags => ({ ...file, tags }))
    ))
  );

  constructor(private service: FileService) { }

  addTag(tagName: string) {
    this.addTag$.next(itemName);
  }
```

Here's a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-71802249?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) demo.

Comment: Finally got some time to play with this, and it has been working the way I have intended so far without issue! I was able to get rid of the subscribe in the ngOnInit() which was going to be another task that was taken care of with this answer thanks!

Comment: So now if I want to add a `removeTag` option, would I place the remove in another switchMap after the first one?

Comment: NVM, looks like I can just do this: `switchMap(file => merge(this.updatedfileTags$, this.delTag$)`

Comment: `delTags$` could become a source for `updatedFileTags$` if that operation returns the full list of tags like `addTag` does. [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-71802249-3bu8tj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 1):

You're missusing the observable. After you subscribe with it, in the template with the async pipe, you should not update it's reference.

If you need to update the data, you must use a Subject.

```
export class AppComponent {
  private readonly data = new BehaviorSubject<FileInfo>(null);
  data$ = this.data.asObservable();

  constructor(
    // Used to mimic server responses
    private readonly server: WebServer
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.server.file().subscribe((result) => this.data.next(result));
  }

  addTag(newTag: string) {
    this.server
      .save(newTag)
      .subscribe((tags) => this.data.next({ ...this.data.value, tags }));
  }
}
```

Also, your service could be a lot simpler:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class WebServer {
  private readonly tags = ['dog', 'cat'];

  file(): Observable<FileInfo> {
    return of({ tags: this.tags });
  }

  save(tag: string) {
    this.tags.push(tag);
    return of(this.tags);
  }
}
```

Here's the working code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-my3wlu?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: I don't want to use `subscribe` as I am trying to follow the declarative pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Try completely converting webserver.service.ts to provide an observables of tags and FileInfo like this:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { concat, Observable, of, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { delay, map, shareReplay, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { FileInfo } from './app.component'; // best practice is to move this to its own file, btw

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class WebServer {
  private fakeServerTagArray = ['dog', 'cat'];
  private readonly initialTags$ = of(this.fakeServerTagArray);
  private readonly tagToSave$: Subject<string> = new Subject();

  public readonly tags$: Observable<string[]> = concat(
    this.initialTags$,
    this.tagToSave$.pipe(
      tap(this.fakeServerTagArray.push),
      delay(100),
      map(() => this.fakeServerTagArray),
      shareReplay(1) // performant if more than one thing might listen, useless if only one thing listens
    )
  );

  public readonly file$: Observable<FileInfo> = this.tags$.pipe(
    map(tags => ({tags})),
    shareReplay(1) // performant if more than one thing might listen, useless if only one thing listens
  );

  save(tag: string): void {
    this.tagToSave$.next(tag);
  }
}
```

and now your AppComponent can just be

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <input #tag /><button (click)="addTag(tag.value)">Add Tag</button>

  <div *ngIf="server.file$ | async as data">
    <div *ngFor="let tag of data.tags">{{ tag }}</div>
  </div>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(
    private readonly server: WebServer;
  ) {}

  addTag(newTag: string) {
    this.server.save(newTag);
  }
}
```

Caveat: If you ever call WebServer.save while WebServer.tags$ or downstream isn't subscribed to, nothing will happen. In your case, no big deal, because the `| async` in your template subscribes. But if you ever split it up so that saving a tag is in a different component, the service will need to be slightly modified to ensure that the "save new tag" server API call is still made.

Comment: class `WebServer` is not a real class, it is only used to mimic what a websocket response would be.

Comment: Best practice is to keep your components as simple and stupid as possible. You should create a service that provides `file$`. That way you can test it, other pages can also use it without duplication, and the data logic is separated from the UI. In this case, if you replaced `initialTags$` with whatever call you initially make to the server that returns a string array of tags, and you replace the tap/delay/map with the server call that saves the tag and returns a new array of tags, your code is done.

Comment: ... and then, *when* the backend details change, you only have to fix it once.